# ejs for loop randering

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am sending three arrays from my node server to `.ejs` page and I want to display as like, [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWIQ2.png)
But I am ending up like,[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imLCt.png)

Here is The code,

```
<div class="webvUI-panel__bd">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="webvUI-media-box webvUI-media-box_appmsg">
        <% for(var i=0; i < image.length; i++) { %>
            <div class="webvUI-media-box__hd">
                <img class="webvUI-media-box__thumb" src="<%= image[i]%>" alt="">
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <div class="webvUI-media-box__bd">
            <% for(var i=0; i < food.length; i++) { %>
                <h4 class="webvUI-media-box__title">
                    <%= food[i] %>
                </h4>
            <% } %>
            <% for(var i=0; i < price.length; i++) { %>
                <p class="webvUI-media-box__desc">
                    <%= price[i] %>$
                </p>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every object has the same attributes such as image, food and price. If you define all these attributes within an object, you could group them together as in the below. Instead of sending them seperately, you can model them inside of an object and then you can loop through that object.

```
<div class="webvUI-panel__bd">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="webvUI-media-box webvUI-media-box_appmsg">
        <% object.forEach(function(obj)) { %>
            <div class="webvUI-media-box__hd">
                <img class="webvUI-media-box__thumb" src="<%= obj.image[i]%>" alt="">
                <%= obj.food[i] %>
                <%= obj.price[i] %>$
            </div>
        <% } %>
    </a>
</div>
```